# Getter was called on null while accessing inherited widget

Tags: dart, flutter

I am having this error while trying to use inherited widget in flutter.

```
The getter 'serviceListBloc' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 3525): Receiver: null
I/flutter ( 3525): Tried calling: serviceListBloc
```

My Code

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

final abc = ServiceProvider.of(context).serviceListBloc;

 return MaterialApp(
  title: 'Learning Json Parse',
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Learning Json Parse'),
    ),
    body: ServiceProvider(
      serviceListBloc: ServiceListBloc(),
      child: StreamBuilder(
      stream: bloc.allServices,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<ServiceList> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.none:
            return Text('Select lot');
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return Text('Awaiting bids...');
          case ConnectionState.active:
          case ConnectionState.done:
             List services = snapshot.data.services;
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: services.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Center(
                  child: Text(snapshot.data.services[index].category),
                );
              },
            );
        }
        return null; // unreachable
      },
    ),
    ),
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      child: Icon(Icons.add),
      onPressed: () => bloc.updateServices(),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}
 }

My Inherited Widget is

```
class ServiceProvider extends InheritedWidget{
   final ServiceListBloc serviceListBloc;

  ServiceProvider({Key key, Widget child, this.serviceListBloc}) 
   : super(key:key, child:child);

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(InheritedWidget oldWidget) => true;

  static ServiceProvider of(BuildContext context) {
    return  (context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(ServiceProvider));
  }

}
```

I was getting the error while trying to receive the inherited widget as abc. Please am i missing something.

I only get this error with

```
  final abc = ServiceProvider.of(context).serviceListBloc;
```

but not with

```
  final abc = ServiceProvider.of(context);
```

and i need to point to the bloc to call my methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don’t have the exception in the first scenario because you are probably assigning `null` to your `abc` (you can debug to check). It’s not an invalid instruction. However, in the second scenario you’re trying to do something like `null.serviceListBloc`, which will trigger the exception.

By looking at your code it doesn’t seem like you’ve a `ServiceProvider` ancestor, you’re trying to access it even before the `MaterialApp` is built, which in its turn, has the `ServiceProvider` as one of its children in the descendant tree.

Comment: Thank you. Your explaination helped decipher what the problem really was. I didnt properly created an inherited widget(ServiceProvider) ancestor.